# NaN:NaN in firefox and IE ,CHROME works fine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

My script is OK in Chrome, but in FireFox and IE the result is: NaN:NaN.
This is my script: Anyone knows whats wrong?

Output of $db[time] is : 2013-10-07 14:28:35 (Timestamp database)

```
<script>
var end = new Date('<?=$db[time]?>');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'ITS NOW TIME!</font><BR><BR>';                
            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);


        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = '<font color="orange">' + minutes + ':';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += '<font color="orange">' + seconds + ' minutes</font>';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the value of $db[time] ?

Comment: and the output of `<?=$db[time]?>` would be?

Comment: 2013-10-07 THE OUTPUT of $db[time] =  2013-10-07 14:28:35

Comment: Do not use font tags!! They are deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Comment: have you tried `new Date().getTime()` instead of doing the comparison and calculations on the `Date` object itself?

Comment: Formatting of the dates! Check this page, it's very useful: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the value of `$db[time]`.

You said in a comment the format of the date/time is `2013-10-07 14:28:35` which is the default DATETIME output for MySQL, when it needs to be `2013-10-07T14:28:35`.

Chrome supports the `2013-10-07 14:28:35` format as a convenience however it's not in the Javascript spec, so not all other browsers do.

Try this:

```
<? echo str_replace(' ', 'T', $db['time']); ?>
```

Comment: This doesnt work: in chrome the output is also: NaN:NaN right now

Comment: What is the output of `str_replace(' ', 'T', $db['time']);`?

Comment: No it works fine in CHROME, sorry my mistake. But in Firefox and IE sitll not working. The output with replace is: 2013-10-07T14:27:56

Comment: In firefox the outpot is: 0000-00-00T00:00:00
In chrome it is: 2013-10-07T14:27:56

Comment: OK: My bad: In Chrome and Firefox the output is: 2013-10-07T14:27:56 But now the counter wont stop counting and counts till the next hour. When its at 0, the counter start again at 60:00 to count to the next hour (15:27:56) then (16:27:56) etc.

Answer (score 2):

javascript time format different from php so firefox will display NaN:NaN:NaN. you should covert time as below:

PHP date format

```html
$yourDate = date("M d, Y H:i:s", strtotime($db['time'])));
```

get time like this

```js
date = new date("<?=$yourDate?>").getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the date string yourself rather than relying on a modern browsers with modern methods, something like the following should be cross-browser friendly. Countdown is in milliseconds, you can format it as you wish.

HTML

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function isGregorianLeapYear(year) {
    return year % 400 === 0 || year % 100 !== 0 && year % 4 === 0;
}

function daysInGregorianMonth(year, month) {
    var days;

    if (month == 2) {
        days = 28;
        if (isGregorianLeapYear(year)) {
            days += 1;
        }
    } else {
        days = 31 - ((month - 1) % 7 % 2);
    }

    return days;
}

function timeStampToDate(timeStamp) {
    var dateObject,
        dateTime,
        date,
        time,
        value;

    if (typeof timeStamp === "string") {
        dateTime = timeStamp.split(" ");
        if (dateTime.length === 2) {
            date = dateTime[0].split("-");
            if (date.length === 3) {
                value = +date[0];
                if (date[0].length === 4 && value >= -9999 && value <= 9999) {
                    value = +date[1];
                    if (date[1].length === 2 && value >= 1 && value <= 12) {
                        date[1] = value - 1;
                        value = +date[2];
                        if (date[2].length === 2 && value >= 1 && value <= daysInGregorianMonth(+date[0], date[1])) {
                            time = dateTime[1].split(":");
                            if (time.length === 3) {
                                value = +time[0];
                                if (time[0].length === 2 && value >= 0 && value <= 23) {
                                    value = +time[1];
                                    if (time[1].length === 2 && value >= 0 && value <= 59) {
                                        value = +time[2];
                                        if (time[2].length === 2 && value >= 0 && value <= 59) {
                                            dateObject = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, date.concat(time)));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (typeof dateObject === "undefined") {
        dateObject = new Date(NaN);
    }

    return dateObject;
}

function emptyNode(node) {
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
}

var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown"),
    end = timeStampToDate("2013-10-07 16:57:00"),
    intervalId;

end = end.getTime() + end.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    if (isNaN(end) || isNaN(now)) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        emptyNode(countdown);
        countdown.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Error"));
    } else if (now < end) {
        emptyNode(countdown);
        countdown.appendChild(document.createTextNode(end - now));
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        emptyNode(countdown);
        countdown.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ITS NOW TIME!"));
    }
}

intervalId = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/RmqRc/)